# If I have the same question open in two tabs, is only one of them "live"?

Tags: discussion, support, live-refresh

I was just looking at some authorization attribute questions and came across an answer from Darin here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503528/1026459 . I had also opened it from a different link because someone mentioned it in chat and I wanted to verify I was looking at the same question.

At this point, I had two tabs open with that same question. I liked part of his answer for calling a view from an attribute which I hadn't seen before so I upvoted it. However, I noticed that on the tab which I did not click upvote, the count was still at 9 (without the +1 from my vote which made it 10). It also did not show an up arrow on the vote.

Is this by design? Perhaps as a result of my vote being handled client side? I was under the impression voting was live refreshing.

Comment: Yes, it syncs but only partially. Votes get updated and you _might_ get edit notifications (you do usually) but the edits don't show immediately unless you click on them. Also, comments as well as your own vote indication (what you noticed) also don't sync.